# Adjust shiny code to generate the results as in the first code

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me tweak the second code below. The first code works normally. In the first I use a database called `Test` and it does exactly what I want. In the second code notice that I have a `df1` database, a function and then it generates a `Test` database. The result generated by this `Test` datbase of the second code is exactly the same as the `Test` database of the first code, the difference is that in the first I am specifying the values of the Test and in the other I use a function to generate. However, in the second code when I run shiny it doesn't show the results, like in the first code, I'd like to adjust that.

**First code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
    coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange'),
                                       br()
                                       
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(
                                         dataTableOutput('table'),
                                         br(), br(), 
                                         downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                                     ),
                                   ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
      }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Second code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
         DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
         DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
return(df1)
  
  }
  
  return_coef <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
    
    x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
    
    x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
    PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
    
    med<-PV %>%
      group_by(Category,Week) %>%
      summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
    
    SPV<-df1%>%
      inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
      mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                      get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                    .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
      select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
    
    SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
    
    mat1 <- df1 %>%
      filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
      select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
      arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
      mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
      filter(cs == 0) %>%
      pull(name)
    
    (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
    
    SPV <- SPV %>%
      filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
      select(-any_of(dropnames))
    
    datas<-SPV %>%
      filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
      group_by(Category) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
      mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
    colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
    
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
    
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
    
    Test<-cbind(df1 %>% select(date2,Category), coef = mapply(return_coef, df1$date2, df1$Category))

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table'),
                                 br(), br(), 
                                 downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                               ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you are calling itself.  Also, it is never used on the server side.  Therefore, you are getting all the variables in your subset data.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

function.test<-function(){

  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
         DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
         DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

  return(df1)

}

return_coef <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {

  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))

  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))

  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x +
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())

  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)

  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)

  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))

  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))

  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")

  datas <- datas %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup

  mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  return(round(as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])))

  # Test<-cbind(df1 %>% select(date2,Category), coef = mapply(return_coef, df1$date2, df1$Category))

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()

                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table'),
                                 br(), br(),
                                 downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                               ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(function.test())

  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    df1 <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) %in% days)
    df2 <- df1 %>% select(date2,Category)
    Test <- cbind(df2, coef = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {return_coef(df1,x[1],x[2])}))
    Test
  })

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2),
                   min   = min(data()$date2),
                   max   = max(data()$date2)
                  )
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks YBS, that's exactly it. Do you know if you can disable dates that are not part of my database in the `daterange`? Because the way it is, it's enabled for all dates

Comment: Adding min and max should help with that - see updated code.  Also, I do not see the issue you noted in the most recent question you posted about coeff values changing when display period in daterange is changed.

Comment: Thanks YBS! Regarding the most recent question, did you use the code I put there? You saw the images that I inserted, until 04/07 are the correct values, but when I changed it to 03/07, the coefficient values changed, for you not?

Comment: No, I used the code in this answer.  Let me try the other code.

Comment: YBS, any suggestions for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622756/delete-calendar-after-pressing-reset-button-on-shiny

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the data you're generating, the dates are strings, not dates.  If you change the `function.test()` definition to the following, it should work:

```
function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= as.Date(c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
         date2 = as.Date(c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
         DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
         DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
  return(df1)
  
}
```

Perhaps you know this already, so I apologize if this additional piece isn't helpful, but I always find it useful to use the `browse()` function to get into the app.  If you put the following in your UI:

```
actionButton("browser", "browser"),
```

and what's below in your `server` function:

```
  observeEvent(input$browser,{
    browser()
  })
```

It will make a button that allows you to look at the reactive elements in your app.  Using the original formulation, you could look at the generated data and its properties:

```
Browse[1]> data()
#        date1      date2 Category      Week DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR09
# 1 2021-06-28 2021-06-30      FDE Wednesday   4    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    3    2
# 2 2021-06-28 2021-06-30      ABC Wednesday   1    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    4    3
# 3 2021-06-28 2021-07-01      FDE    Friday   6    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    5    4
# 4 2021-06-28 2021-07-02      ABC    Friday   1    4    0    0    5    0    5    0    0    0

Browse[1]> str(data())
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  14 variables:
# $ date1   : chr  "2021-06-28" "2021-06-28" "2021-06-28" "2021-06-28"
# $ date2   : chr  "2021-06-30" "2021-06-30" "2021-07-01" "2021-07-02"
# $ Category: chr  "FDE" "ABC" "FDE" "ABC"
# $ Week    : chr  "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Friday" "Friday"
# $ DR1     : num  4 1 6 1
# $ DR01    : num  4 1 4 4
# $ DR02    : num  4 2 6 0
# $ DR03    : num  9 5 4 0
# $ DR04    : num  5 4 3 5
# $ DR05    : num  5 4 5 0
# $ DR06    : num  2 4 3 5
# $ DR07    : num  2 5 4 0
# $ DR08    : num  3 4 5 0
# $ DR09    : num  2 3 4 0
```

This makes it clear that the date variables are character strings.  You could also look at `data_subset()` to verify that it doesn't have any data:

```
Browse[1]> data_subset()
# [1] date1    date2    Category Week     DR1      DR01     DR02     DR03     DR04     DR05     DR06     DR07     DR08     DR09    
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

This would allow you to do some digging:

```
Browse[1]> days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
Browse[1]> days
# [1] "2021-06-30" "2021-07-01" "2021-07-02"
Browse[1]> data()$date2 %in% days
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Browse[1]> class(days)
# [1] "Date"
Browse[1]> class(data()$date2)
# [1] "character"
```

This allows you to identify that the `date2` variable is a different class than the `days` vector which is the crux of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. I made this adjustment that you commented in `df1`, it even generated a table in shiny but notice that the generated table is not the same as the first code. The table of first code only has the date2, category and coef columns. The table for code 2 would have to be the same as for the first.