# Delete calendar after pressing reset button on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to do the following: When I insert any excel file into `fileInput`, a calendar will be loaded. If I press reset buttom, the calendar is not deleted, then when I press reset, I would like only `fileInput` to be left. I know it's possible using the `shinyjs::hide` package, but I don't want to use that package because it doesn't work very well for me. I would like another alternative.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-04"),
         Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,0),
         DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  
  return(df1)
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  maxrange <-  range(min(0, datas$Numbers, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
  maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] - (maxrange[2] %%10) + 35
  
  max<-max(0, datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max),  ylim= c(0,maxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3) & length(unique(datas$Numbers)) == 1){
    yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,datas$Days), c(yz, datas$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       br(),
                                       uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                       br(),
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                       
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      df3 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
      return(df3)
    }
  })
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"), multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx"))
  })
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              value = min(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    df1 <- data()
    updateDateInput(session, 'database', value = NA)
    
    output$fileInput <- renderUI({
      fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"), multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx"))
    })
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe something like a conditionalPanel, which relies on fileInput to show the calendar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686581/make-conditionalpanel-depend-on-files-uploaded-with-fileinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `insertUI` and `removeUI()`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-04"),
         Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,0),
         DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  
  return(df1)
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  maxrange <-  range(min(0, datas$Numbers, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
  maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] - (maxrange[2] %%10) + 35
  
  max<-max(0, datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max),  ylim= c(0,maxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3) & length(unique(datas$Numbers)) == 1){
    yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,datas$Days), c(yz, datas$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       br(),
                                       uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                       br(),
                                       # uiOutput("date"),
                                       tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
                                       #uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                       
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"), multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx"))
  })
  
  data2 <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      df3 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
      return(df3)
    }
  })
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"), multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx"))
  })
  
  inserted <- c()
  observeEvent(input$file,{
    id <- paste0('txt')
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = tags$div(
        dateInput(input = "date2", 
                  label = h4("Data"),
                  min = min(data()$date2),
                  max = max(data()$date2),
                  value = min(data()$date2),
                  format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                  datesdisabled = disabled),
        selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=""),
        id = id
      )
    )
    inserted <<- id
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$date2, {
    req(data(),input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    updateSelectInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "code",
                      choices = unique(df2$Category)
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code,data())
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    
    updateDateInput(session, 'data2', value = NA)
    updateSelectInput(session, "code", choices = character(0), selected = character(0))
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#', inserted)
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much YBS!